# How to add new data to an array in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

What is wrong in my code ?
I would like to add all urls from website to the array

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://globalthiel.pl'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url.append(link.get('href').text)
for i in urls:
    print(i, end="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. Replace

```py
url.append(link.get('href').text)
```

with

```py
urls.append(link.get('href').text)
```

Comment: oh... yeap should be urls. Thx mate